# What might cause java.lang.OutOfMemoryError here when using Protocol Buffers?

Tags: java, redis, protocol-buffers, jedis

Running the code below results in an exception regarding the Java heap space.

Coming from .NET and having a handle on how GC works there I wonder whether there is something I need to consider, in terms of memory management, when trying to run the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, ParseException, IOException {

    Jedis jedis = new Jedis("<HostName>");

    TimeSeriesPoints retrieved = null;

    while(!finished) {

        try {

            finished = true;

            List<String> keys = getNextFiftyKeys();

            String[] cacheKeys = new String[keys.size()];

            List<String> cacheResults = jedis.mget(keys.toArray(cacheKeys));

            List<TimeSeries> cachedTimeSeries = new ArrayList<TimeSeries>();

            for(String cacheResult : cacheResults){
                try {
                    retrieved = TimeSeriesPoints.parseFrom(cacheResult.getBytes());

                    TimeSeries timeSeries = new TimeSeries(retrieved.getName(), retrieved.getPointsList());

                    cachedTimeSeries.add(timeSeries);
                } 
                catch (InvalidProtocolBufferException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            long pointsCount = 0;
            for(TimeSeries timeSeries : cachedTimeSeries){
                pointsCount += timeSeries.points.length;
            }

            System.out.println("retrieved: " + cachedTimeSeries.size());
            System.out.println("points:" + pointsCount);            
    }
}
```

An exception is thrown at **TimeSeriesPoints.parseFrom** with stack trace as follows. Not sure why exactly.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacity(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(Unknown Source)
    at com.wimiro.caching.TimeSeriesProtos$TimeSeriesPoints.<init>(TimeSeriesProtos.java:115)
    at com.wimiro.caching.TimeSeriesProtos$TimeSeriesPoints.<init>(TimeSeriesProtos.java:82)
    at com.wimiro.caching.TimeSeriesProtos$TimeSeriesPoints$1.parsePartialFrom(TimeSeriesProtos.java:151)
    at com.wimiro.caching.TimeSeriesProtos$TimeSeriesPoints$1.parsePartialFrom(TimeSeriesProtos.java:1)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialFrom(AbstractParser.java:141)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:176)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:188)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:193)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:49)
    at com.wimiro.caching.TimeSeriesProtos$TimeSeriesPoints.parseFrom(TimeSeriesProtos.java:958)
    at program.main(program.java:77)
```

This blows up trying to read 800 time series (each with ~4000 data points). As I'm only dealing with 50 time series at a time in this example I don't expect the memory footprint to grow significantly.

In .NET I've no difficulty doing this. Time to learn me some Java then. What do I need to read?

Comment: Can you add the code of TimeSeriesPoints.parseFrom(...) ? Is it leaky?

Comment: It's within protobuf-java2.5.0.jar. It would be quite surprising to have a leak here. http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java/2.5.0

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get byte arrays from java String (UTF-16) which are got from jedis (with SafeEncoder to traduce UTF-16 to bytearray) which calls redis (C char 8 bit encoding). I think this is the root of your problem, your java String is probably incorrect and that makes protobuf fail.

You should try using the byte array signatures from jedis:

```
final List<byte[]> mget = jedis.mget(byteArray1, byteArray2, ...);
```

And then try to use protobuf on the byte array. Also check how you insert your data in redis with jedis, in all cases it is recommended to use the byte array signatures with binary data.

Comment: **jedis.mget** returns **List<String>** and the problem seems to be with **TimeSeriesPoints.parseFrom**

Comment: @ofraski No, there is an overloading on mget. You can use directly bytearrays and thus bypassing traduction errors between String and byte data.

Answer (score 1):

Protobuf-Java unfortunately uses a very inefficient encoding for repeated primitive types -- each element is boxed.  E.g. a `repeated int32` is represented as `ArrayList<Int>`.  In theory this could be optimized in the protobuf implementation but this had not been done last I knew.  I'd guess your problem stems from this.

If you haven't already, try increasing the JVM's max heap size (e.g. `-Xmx2g` for 2GB).